# How to instantiate H264 Encoder on WinRT Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, h.264, video-encoding, wrl

I want to be able to encode video frames using Media Foundation IMFTransform for H264 Video Encoding. That's easily doable in Win32, where you can use MFTEnumEx to enumerate the transforms and find the H264 encoder.

However, on WinRT (Store Apps), I can't find a way to instantiate.
I've noticed there's a class CMSH264EncoderMFT, but there's no definition for the CLSID to use on CoCreateInstance.

With:

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUnknown), (void **)&pUnknown);
```

CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT is undefined for WinRT apps.

And tried:

```
ComPtr<CMSH264EncoderMFT> encoder = Make<CMSH264EncoderMFT>();
```

It says the class CMSH264EncoderMFT is incomplete, and says "use of undefined type 'CMSH264EncoderMFT'". Don't even know if the syntax for Make is correct or appropriate...

Does anyone have a clue on how to do this for WinRT?

Comment: Hi, I cannot give you the correct advice, but while I faces with similar problem I have decided to use the next trick [Using Free-COM DLL in Windows Store C++ Project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/win8devsupport/2013/05/19/using-free-com-dll-in-windows-store-c-project/). Ideas is that from code of WindowsStore application for Desktop versions of Windows possible call some COM DLL. IT DOES NOT WORK for Windows WinRT, but amount of devices with such version of Windows is very low. This solution is not for Universal App - only Desktop.

Comment: Hi @EvgenyPereguda, thank you. It's interesting to know I can free load a COM. But I really need this for mobile. The only way I know I can encode for mobile is with a Sink Writer, but that gives me the overhead of the file format (say mp4).. I really wanted to get the sample from the `IMFTransform::ProcessOutput` to work with...

Answer (score 0):

Use [MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388105(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a file writer first. Then, use [MFCreateMediaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create an IMFMediaType. Set up its properties, one of which will be the output format: use [SetGUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970530(v=vs.85).aspx) method on the media type with MF_MT_SUBTYPE guid and specify MFVideoFormat_H264 as the argument. Finally, use [AddStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374646(v=vs.85).aspx) method on the sink writer to set the media type to it.

There's an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx) (you'll need to modify it a bit when it sets MF_MT_SUBTYPE).

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually doing that right now, but the problem is that I don't get the codec output sample, it just saves to a stream already formatted as a file (such as mp4). What I need is the video sample I can get on desktop by instantiating the codec's IMFTransform.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot instantiate object via CMSH264EncoderMFT because it  DOES NOT have some interfaces which MUST have object in WinRT for example [IInspectable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br205821(v=vs.85).aspx) - `Provides functionality required for all Windows Runtime classes`. CMSH264EncoderMFT IS NOT WinRT class. You can try resolve your task by function [MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388103(v=vs.85).aspx) - this function takes an object with interface [IMFMediaSink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694262(v=vs.85).aspx). It is possible write code for object with `IMFMediaSink` interface and receive samples from `IMFTransform::ProcessOutput`. I just point your attention - you cannot instantiate in WindowsStore code objects which IS NOT Windows Runtime classes.

Regards,
Evgeny Pereguda

Comment: That answer makes no sense. CoCreateInstance is a function that creates COM objects, not Windows Runtime objects. The actual reason it fails is because that class is not available for Windows Store applications. There are many COM classes that are available and don't implement IInspectable, though.

Comment: I have wrote that it is possible create COM objects via `Using Free-COM DLL in Windows Store C++ Project.` However, `Joao Carrion` tried use CMSH264EncoderMFT from context of WindowsStore like accessible GUID. I point that it is impossible use Free-COM on WinRT environment which is the level abstraction from the specific platform.

Comment: Hi @EvgenyPereguda, are you saying I need to implement an IMFMediaSink, and, I'm assuming, probably an IMFStreamSink as well to be able to get the output frames from the H264 codec? I'm looking into that now, but the documentation is quite confusing if you don't want to do the standard write to file, play from file routing.

Comment: Hi, I can say that Media Foundation is complex framework, but it is only one way for working with video in `WiindowsStore` applications. About implementation of `IMSMediaSink` - I can advise research [WindowsSDK7 Samples](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/mediafoundation) - it includes `WavSink Sample` example code. It is sample for Windows 7, but it can be adaptable for `WiindowsStore` app, and it includes only 3 files - it is more easy research.